# Count as duplicates similar values

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have following tables:

```
    Orders 
    order_id
    9
    10
    11

    Order_details 
    order_id, product_id  
    9,        7    
    10,       5
    10,       6
    11,       6
    11,       7

    Products 
    product_id, product_name, price
    5,          potato,       4.99
    6,          potato *,     7.5
    7,          orange,       7.99
```

I already received feedback how to find orders where product names are duplicated, but now situation is a little more complicated as it turned out duplicated positions have additional sign ' *' after it's name as showed above.

How to add to this query possibility to count ONLY orders where there is one product without additional characters and other with it?

for example 'potato' and 'potato' would be ignored, 'potato *' and 'potato *' would be also ignored but order with 'potato' and 'potato *' would be in the results

```
select od.order_id
from order_details od join
     products p
     on od.product_id = p.product_id
group by od.order_id
having count(p.product_name) > count(distinct p.product_name)
```

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to just do a simple replacement to remove `*` from the product name:

```
SELECT
    od.order_id
FROM order_details od
INNER JOIN products p
    ON od.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY
    od.order_id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_name) <>
    COUNT(DISTINCT REPLACE(p.product_name, ' *', ''));
```

### Demo

The demo is given for MySQL, but the same query should run on at least several other databases.

Ideally, it would be better to do a regex replacement on the product name, which would avoid the possibility that space followed by `*` happens to appear elsewhere as a legitimate part of the product name.

**Edit:**

Since you are using Postgres we can in fact do a more targeted regex replacement:

```
SELECT
    od.order_id
FROM order_details od
INNER JOIN products p
    ON od.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY
    od.order_id
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_name) <>
    COUNT(DISTINCT REGEXP_REPLACE(p.product_name, ' \*$', ''));
```

### Demo

Comment: Unfortunately that would not solve my issue as I need to know only duplicates that have * in the name

Comment: somehow on this demo Its working as expected but in my DB there are also other results.. cannot find out why. But I know theoritically how to solve it, there should be added restriction that orders with same product name AND different product_id should be in the results, how to implement it both?

Comment: Ok, the second edit specifically for postgress is working perfectly!
But I'm curious also how to implement mechanism from my comment above

Comment: @sh4rkyy Given that my answer is already too long, I will just add a comment that you may select all orders whose IDs match what my query returns.  In this case, only order 10 matches, so you would just select all products for that order.

Comment: But I want to try another approach (learn something more) and to double check correction of the results. You can remove 1st part of the answer if you would be so nice and help me with this one :) I guess it should be some subquery included ? To check if doubled names have different IDs? I'm not much familiar with nesting and its syntax

Comment: I would actually rather leave the first part of my query, because it would run on most other databases which don't have regex support.  If you have a follow-up, then maybe ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could *chain* on the(longest) initial substring:

---

```
CREATE TABLE products (
        product_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , product_name text
        , price DECIMAL(8,2)
        );

INSERT  INTO products(product_id, product_name, price) VALUES
    (5,          'potato',       4.99)
    ,(6,          'potato *',     7.5)
    ,(1,          'potatoes',     7.48) -- added these
    ,(2,          'potatoe',     7.49)  --
    ,(7,          'orange',       7.99)
        ;

ALTER TABLE products
        ADD COLUMN parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES products(product_id)
        , ADD COLUMN canonical_id INTEGER REFERENCES products(product_id);

UPDATE products
SET canonical_id = product_id;

SELECT*FROM products;

WITH xxx AS  ( select product_id, product_name
        , length(product_name) AS len
        FROM products
        )
UPDATE products dst
SET parent_id = src.product_id
FROM xxx src
-- WHERE position (src.product_name IN dst.product_name) = 1
WHERE dst.product_name LIKE src.product_name ||'%'::text
AND src.len > 4
AND src.len < length(dst.product_name)
 AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM xxx nx
        WHERE dst.product_name LIKE nx.product_name|| '%'::text
        AND nx.len < length(dst.product_name)
        AND nx.len > src.len
        AND nx.product_id <> dst.product_id
        )
        ;

SELECT*FROM products;

WITH yyy AS  ( select product_id, product_name
        , length(product_name) AS len
        FROM products
        )
UPDATE products dst
SET canonical_id = src.product_id
FROM yyy src
WHERE dst.product_name LIKE src.product_name ||'%'::text
AND src.len > 4
AND src.len < length(dst.product_name)
 AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM yyy nx
        WHERE dst.product_name LIKE nx.product_name|| '%'::text
        AND nx.len < src.len
        )
        ;

SELECT*FROM products;
```

---

Result:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 5
ALTER TABLE
UPDATE 5
 product_id | product_name | price | parent_id | canonical_id 
------------+--------------+-------+-----------+--------------
          5 | potato       |  4.99 |           |            5
          6 | potato *     |  7.50 |           |            6
          1 | potatoes     |  7.48 |           |            1
          2 | potatoe      |  7.49 |           |            2
          7 | orange       |  7.99 |           |            7
(5 rows)

UPDATE 3
 product_id | product_name | price | parent_id | canonical_id 
------------+--------------+-------+-----------+--------------
          5 | potato       |  4.99 |           |            5
          7 | orange       |  7.99 |           |            7
          6 | potato *     |  7.50 |         5 |            6
          2 | potatoe      |  7.49 |         5 |            2
          1 | potatoes     |  7.48 |         2 |            1
(5 rows)

UPDATE 3
 product_id | product_name | price | parent_id | canonical_id 
------------+--------------+-------+-----------+--------------
          5 | potato       |  4.99 |           |            5
          7 | orange       |  7.99 |           |            7
          6 | potato *     |  7.50 |         5 |            5
          2 | potatoe      |  7.49 |         5 |            5
          1 | potatoes     |  7.48 |         2 |            5
(5 rows)
```

---

Note: this may need some additional heuristic tweaking. (or even manual editing)